# How to load data into local test environment DataStore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I need to load some data from a CSV file and populate my local test GAE environment DataStore. I figure I need to use the [NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/). 
My question is how to direct the operations to my local test environment rather than my production cloud environment?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local datastore emulation is done by the development server itself, see [Using the local Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore).

So simply by running the script that translates the CSV file into the NDB writing calls inside the development server would get you what you need.

To run the script inside the server you can make it a part of the app itself or you can execute it (or call its relevant function) inside the `Interactive Console` from the local admin page, which you can access at the URL displayed when the devserver starts:

> INFO     2017-09-19 13:34:40,772 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin
>   server at: http://localhost:8000

You can also load and use code from your app itself inside the interactive console script, just as it would be part of your app.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Works great!